# Facade generic é possivel?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, genéricos

Boa tarde
Estou estudando por conta orientação a objetos, e no meio dos estudos apareceram vários padrões e com eles um monte de confusão

Minha duvida é é possível ter um FACADE genérico. ou nada a ver que estou falando?

Estava vendo essas [videos aulas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nI4jljsi5rQ&index=6&list=PLTHYycROn5oIpllleLD20_DFyjMzc1MTH)

Onde ele cria

- LivroFacade
- InterfaceLivroDao
- LivroDAO
- LivroController
- Livro (model)

No exemplo dele, foi um cadastro de livros, porem, estou fazendo um cadastro de produtos, onde haverá PRODUTOS e MARCAS

Já criei a interface iDao usando generic

```
package br.com.jcom.dao;

import java.util.List;

public interface IDao<T> {

    String getNomeTabela();

    int insert(T... elementos);

    int update(T... elementos);

    int delete(T... elementos);

    //T selectCodigo(String codigo);

    //T select(String sql, String... paramentros);

    List<T> selectAll();

    //List<T> selectAll(String sql, String... paramentros);

}
```

Já criei os models PRODUTOS e MARCAS

Também marcaDao

```
package br.com.jcom.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.jcom.factory.Conexao;
import br.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;

public class MarcaDao implements IDao<Marca> {

    private String nomeTabela = "Marcas";
    private Connection connection;

    public MarcaDao() {
        this.connection = new Conexao().getConnection();

    }

    @Override
    public String getNomeTabela() {
        return nomeTabela;
    }

    @Override
    public int insert(Marca... elementos) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + nomeTabela + " (marca) VALUES (?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int result = 0;

        for (Marca marca : elementos) {
            try {
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setString(1, marca.getMarca());
                result = stmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally{
                Conexao.close(connection, stmt, null);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Marca... elementos) {

        String sql = "UPDATE " + nomeTabela + "SET marca = ? WHERE MarcaID = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int result = 0;

        for (Marca marca : elementos) {
            try {
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setString(1, marca.getMarca());
                stmt.setLong(2, marca.getMarcaID());
                result = stmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                Conexao.close(connection, stmt, null);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Marca... elementos) {

        String sql = "DELETE FROM " + nomeTabela + "WHERE MarcaID = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        int result = 0;

        for (Marca marca : elementos) {
            try {
                stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setLong(1, marca.getMarcaID());
                result = stmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                Conexao.close(connection, stmt, null);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Marca> selectAll() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + nomeTabela;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        List<Marca> marcas = new ArrayList<Marca>();
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Marca marca = new Marca();
                marca.setMarcaID(rs.getLong("marcaID"));
                marca.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));

                marcas.add(marca);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            Conexao.close(connection, stmt, rs);
        }
        return marcas;

    }

}
```

E o marcaController

```
package br.com.jcom.controller;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.jcom.facade.DaoFacade;
import br.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;

public class MarcaController {

    private DaoFacade marcaFacade;

    public MarcaController() {
        this.marcaFacade = new DaoFacade<Marca>();
    }

    public int addMarca(Marca marca){
        return marcaFacade.insert(marca);

    }

    public int updateMarca(Marca marca){
        return marcaFacade.update(marca);

    }

    public int deleteMarca(Marca marca){
        return marcaFacade.delete(marca);

    }

    public List<Marca> selectMarcas(){
        return marcaFacade.selectAll();

    }
}
```

Bom agora no FACADE é que nao estou conseguindo entender muito bem a logica

```
package br.com.jcom.facade;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.jcom.dao.IDao;
import br.com.jcom.dao.MarcaDao;

public class DaoFacade<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private IDao dao;

    public DaoFacade() {
        this.dao = new MarcaDao();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int insert(T... elementos) {
        return dao.insert(elementos);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int update(T... elementos) {
        return dao.update(elementos);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int delete(T... elementos) {
        return dao.delete(elementos);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> selectAll() {
        return dao.selectAll();

    }

}
```

Quando eu crio o construtor

```
public DaoFacade() {
        this.dao = new MarcaDao();
}
```

Ao invés de colocar (= new MarcaDao ();) existe a possibilidade de passar uma classe genérica para quando eu = new ProdutoDAO, eu eu estou confundindo tudo??

MarcaGUI > btnSalvar

```
btnSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Marca marca = new Marca();

            if (Funcoes.validaCampos(panel) == true) {
                marca.setMarca(tfMarca.getText());
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Preenchimento de campos (*) obrigatórios");
                return;
            }

            int result = 0;

            if (idMarca == null) {
                result = new MarcaController().addMarca(marca);
            } else {
                marca.setMarcaID(idMarca);
                result = new MarcaController().updateMarca(marca);
                idMarca = null;
            }

            if (result == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Concluido");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao salvar");
            }

            refreshTable();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Essa classe `DaoFacade` no código exemplo não é de fato uma "facade", pois ela não está simplificando o acesso a uma API mais complexa. Eu recomendaria ler a descrição completa do "pattern" Facade no livro original (Design Patterns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por aquilo que vejo no código a classe `DaoFacade`é uma classe genérica, ou seja está preparada para aquilo que você pretende.

Ao instanciá-la você indica qual a classe que ela irá utilizar.

O seu construtor será qualquer coisa do género:

```
public class DaoFacade<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private T dao;

    public DaoFacade() {
        this.dao = new T();//Não é possível em JAVA - Não compila

    }
    .......
    .......
    .......
}
```

No entanto, isto não é suficiente, porque os métodos terão de receber um tipo que é diferente para cada `Dao`. Assim, a classe `DaoFacade`, terá de ter outro tipo genérico:

```
public class DaoFacade<TDao, TEntity> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private TDao dao;

    public DaoFacade() {
        this.dao = new TDao();//Não é possível em JAVA - Não compila

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int insert(TEntity... elementos) {
        return dao.insert(elementos);

    }
    .......
    .......
    .......
}
```

Esta solução requer que seja criada uma instância do parâmetro genérico, que não pode ser feito da forma habitual: `dao = new ();`

Assim, a forma correta é fazer uso da *Interface* `IDao` e passar o Dao no construtor:

```
public class DaoFacade<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private IDao dao;

    public DaoFacade(IDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;

    }
    //O resto do código ficaria igual
    .......
    .......
    .......
}
```

Neste caso `T` seria a entidade a processar e todos os métodos ficam como você tem.
Para criar uma nova instância de DaoFacade:

```
new DaoFacad<Marca>(new MarcaDao());
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lbr.com.jcom.modelo.Marca;
 at br.com.jcom.dao.MarcaDao.insert(MarcaDao.java:1)
at br.com.jcom.facade.DaoFacade.insert(DaoFacade.java:18)
at br.com.jcom.controller.MarcaController.addMarca(MarcaController.java:18)
 at br.com.jcom.gui.MarcaGUI$3.actionPerformed(MarcaGUI.java:140)

Comment: O problema parece ter origem na classe `MarcaGUI` à qual eu não tenho acesso.

Comment: BOm, vc me ajudou bastante já, vou tentar resolver,
Muito obrigado

Comment: Ta dando problema nessa linha
if (idMarca == null) {
     result = new MarcaController().addMarca(marca);
    } else {

Comment: A variável `marca` é do tipo `Marca`? O erro está a dizer que ela é do tipo `Object`

Comment: sim, é do tipo marca

Comment: editei a pergunta colocando a btnSalvar actionPerformed

Comment: Não encontro nenhum problema.

Comment: eu tbm nao, mas retorna erro.
Como posso upar o fonte para você poder me ajudar?

Comment: upei no mega: https://mega.co.nz/#!Pp1kGAhL!e7G1NF6T6zcMPKAdZlHof8Eyw48fppR_SsFJY-2Zw7M

tem o banco tbm, é sqlserver 2005

Comment: Não posso ajudar mais porque o meu IDE só está configurado para Android. Faça outra pergunta, mas tente simplificar o código que postar.

Comment: entendo ok, muito obrigado então, já me ajudou bastante.
:)

Comment: Opa, pode deixar.